# How to make java class thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a java class as below

```
 class User {

    String name;
    String phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

}
```

The way this class is used is, for every thread 1 object of this User class is created. Now since there is one copy of object for every thread, can i call this class as thread safe?

Do I need to synchronize these methods?

Comment: You only need to synchronize when multiple threads share a resource and if each thread has got its own copy of object, you don't need synchronization.

Comment: If each incoming thread has its own instance of the class, then you _don't_ need to worry about thread safety, assuming only that thread which owns the instance would be accessing it.

Comment: This is a *really* complicated question. The simple answer is to make the class immutable (all fields final), which is thread-safe and a good idea whenever practical anyway.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/7-techniques-for-thread-safe-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you presented it, if each thread has its one copy, then it can be called thread-safe, as maximum of accessing threads is one.

Another thing - if you declare your fields as `private` and create the instance of that class as `final`, then it's immutable (`final User user = new User(...)`). There are no setters, so the object cannot be modified as well as it cannot change its reference. If you wanted to keep the immutability, you would have to make setters return a new instance of this object with changed fields.

@markspace noticed, that better approach would be to declare fields as final, because if you use the previous one and make `User` a member of some class, it won't work (unless final).

Comment: Not the object, no.  The fields themselves have to be declared `final`.  Final fields have special memory visibility semantics just like `volatile` and the JVM doesn't make the object immutable unless the fields are declared `final`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And how about the case that I showed? Isn't the `final` object wiithout methods modifying it immutable?

Comment: Unless you mean something else, you can't get an immutable object just by declaring `final class`.  The fields themselves must be final.  Here's a link to the spec, note the title of this section is "Final Field Semantics," the spec only defines immutable (and thread safe) objects for that case.  Simply not changing a value isn't enough. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Comment: I mean `final` instance, on the client side: `final User user = new ...`

Comment: OK, well you should clarify your answer, it seems like you were saying something different.  But be careful because if `user` isn't a field (say if it's a local variable) then the `final` keyword doesn't do anything special.

Answer (score 2):

For a class to be thread safe, no matter how many threads are accessing it, its invariants and post-conditions should hold true.

For this class, although there are no write methods, you still need to synchronize the reads. This is because the compiler can cache the state variables (in this case `name` and `phone`) for each thread (remember each thread has its own set of registers). Thus, if one thread updates the value of any of the state variables, the other thread may not see it and it may read a stale value.

A very easy way do avoid this would be to make the state variables `volatile`. It's a weak synchronization primitive though, and does not provide atomic behavior like `synchronized` does.

Here's the proper way to make this class thread safe:

```
 class User {

    GuardedBy("this")String name;
    GuardedBy("this")String phone;

    public synchronized String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public synchronized String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

}
```

Note: Each state variable can use a different lock, depending upon your requirements. I have assumed that somehow both of these variables participate in an invariant together.

Weak synchronization:

```
 class User {

    volatile String name;
    volatile String phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

}
```

For `synchronized` methods, every time a thread invokes them, it flushes its cache and reads the latest value from memory, and every time it exists a `synchronized` method, it puts the latest values of the variables in memory.

Stale reads can be even more dangerous with `64b` `double` and `long`, as writes and reads to these data type in Java is not atomic, and can be done in 2 `32b` operations. This can lead to some very bad consequences.

Edit: Just saw that each thread will have its own copy of the object. In that case, no synchronization is needed.

Comment: You have some glaring issues with the code snippets provided, among them being the misspelling of `synchronized` as well as the exclusion of the annotation `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Thread Safe Class means that every changes (getting/setting values) into your `POJO` class are made `Thread Safely`.

It can be achieved by synchronization mechanism.

The general solution is to use **keyword** `synchronized` on the methods or even on your any private logically used object for this purpose.

This **keyword** just locks the object and you are guaranteed that only one thread will be available to access this method at any given time.

But the best practice (optimized solution) is to reduce code critical section and don't always use `synchronized` for an easy/"fast" solution.